# Given points, calculate normals and perform polygonal surface reconstruction in CGAL

Tags: c++, type-conversion, cgal, normals

I have .xyz files and I want to recreate the surface using 'polygonal surface reconstruction' in CGAL. Normals are needed to reconstruct the surface, so I want to first calculate these in CGAL and then use the points and their normals as input for the polygonal surface reconstruction.

However, the output and input types are different for both:

The output of the normal estimation is a list of vectorpairs, see https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Point_set_processing_3/index.html#Point_set_processing_3NormalOrientation : 12.1.1 Example; while the input for polygonal surface reconstruction is a point_vector ((https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Polygonal_surface_reconstruction/index.html).

I tried to create a "convert_function" which converts the data formats, but I am not a C++ programmer thus I have difficulty converting. If anybody could help me with this, that would be great, because I've been stuck on it for hours. My goal is to make this process as time efficient as possible, so better ideas on how to tackle this problem are highly appreciated.

data types:

->Normal calculation:

```
typedef std::pair<Point, Vector> PointVectorPair;
```

->Surface reconstruction:

```
typedef boost::tuple<Point, Vector, int> PNI;
typedef std::vector<PNI> Point_vector;
typedef CGAL::Nth_of_tuple_property_map<0, PNI> Point_map;
typedef CGAL::Nth_of_tuple_property_map<1, PNI> Normal_map;
typedef CGAL::Nth_of_tuple_property_map<2, PNI> Plane_index_map;
```

My invert function does not work because the syntax is not correct:

```
std::vector<PNI> convert_function(const std::list<PointVectorPair>& list)
{
    std::vector<PNI> out;//a temporary object to store the output

    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < list.size(); ++i) {
    {   
        out[i].get<0>() = list[i].get<0>();
        out[i].get<1>() = list[i].get<1>();

    }
    return out;
}
```

A little further on I then use the following:

```
std::vector<PNI> points2; // store points
points2 = convert_function(points);
```

The complete code right now is the following:

```
#include <CGAL/Exact_predicates_inexact_constructions_kernel.h>
#include <CGAL/IO/read_xyz_points.h>
#include <CGAL/IO/Writer_OFF.h>
#include <CGAL/property_map.h>
#include <CGAL/Surface_mesh.h>
#include <CGAL/Shape_detection/Efficient_RANSAC.h>
#include <CGAL/Polygonal_surface_reconstruction.h>
//extras formal calculation
#include <CGAL/compute_average_spacing.h>
#include <CGAL/pca_estimate_normals.h>
#include <CGAL/mst_orient_normals.h>
#include <utility> // defines std::pair
#include <list>

///////////// TRY TO COMBINE NORMAL CALCULATION + RANSAC + POLYFIT

#ifdef CGAL_USE_SCIP  // defined (or not) by CMake scripts, do not define by hand

#include <CGAL/SCIP_mixed_integer_program_traits.h>
typedef CGAL::SCIP_mixed_integer_program_traits<double>                        MIP_Solver;

#elif defined(CGAL_USE_GLPK)  // defined (or not) by CMake scripts, do not define by hand

#include <CGAL/GLPK_mixed_integer_program_traits.h>
typedef CGAL::GLPK_mixed_integer_program_traits<double>                        MIP_Solver;

#endif


#if defined(CGAL_USE_GLPK) || defined(CGAL_USE_SCIP)

#include <CGAL/Timer.h>

#include <fstream>


typedef CGAL::Exact_predicates_inexact_constructions_kernel Kernel;

typedef Kernel::Point_3 Point;
typedef Kernel::Vector_3 Vector;

// Point with normal, and plane index
// 
typedef boost::tuple<Point, Vector, int> PNI;
typedef std::vector<PNI> Point_vector;

//bij normals calc: Point with normal vector stored in a std::pair.
//typedef std::pair<Point, Vector> PointVectorPair;

typedef CGAL::Nth_of_tuple_property_map<0, PNI> Point_map;
typedef CGAL::Nth_of_tuple_property_map<1, PNI> Normal_map;
typedef CGAL::Nth_of_tuple_property_map<2, PNI> Plane_index_map;

typedef std::pair<Point, Vector> PointVectorPair;

typedef CGAL::Shape_detection::Efficient_RANSAC_traits<Kernel, Point_vector, Point_map, Normal_map> Traits;

typedef CGAL::Shape_detection::Efficient_RANSAC<Traits> Efficient_ransac;
typedef CGAL::Shape_detection::Plane<Traits> Plane;
typedef CGAL::Shape_detection::Point_to_shape_index_map<Traits> Point_to_shape_index_map;

typedef CGAL::Polygonal_surface_reconstruction<Kernel> Polygonal_surface_reconstruction;
typedef CGAL::Surface_mesh<Point> Surface_mesh;


// Concurrency
typedef CGAL::Parallel_if_available_tag Concurrency_tag;


std::vector<PNI> convert_function(const std::list<PointVectorPair>& list)
{
    std::vector<PNI> out;//a temporary object to store the output    
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < list.size(); ++i) {
    {   
        out[i].get<0>() = list[i].get<0>();
        out[i].get<1>() = list[i].get<1>();
        
    }
    return out;
}

/*
* This example first extracts planes from the input point cloud
* (using RANSAC with default parameters) and then reconstructs
* the surface model from the planes.
*/

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    const char* fname = (argc > 1) ? argv[1] : "data/47038.xyz";
    // Reads a .xyz point set file in points[].
    std::list<PointVectorPair> points;
    std::ifstream stream(fname);
    if (!stream ||
        !CGAL::read_xyz_points(stream,
            std::back_inserter(points),
            CGAL::parameters::point_map(CGAL::First_of_pair_property_map<PointVectorPair>())))
    {
        std::cerr << "Error: cannot read file " << fname << std::endl;
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    std::cout << "Calculating normals...";

    CGAL::Timer t;
    t.start();

    // Estimates normals direction.
    // Note: pca_estimate_normals() requires a range of points
    // as well as property maps to access each point's position and normal.
    const int nb_neighbors = 18; // K-nearest neighbors = 3 rings
    if (argc > 2 && std::strcmp(argv[2], "-r") == 0) // Use a fixed neighborhood radius
    {
        // First compute a spacing using the K parameter
        double spacing
            = CGAL::compute_average_spacing<Concurrency_tag>
            (points, nb_neighbors,
                CGAL::parameters::point_map(CGAL::First_of_pair_property_map<PointVectorPair>()));
        // Then, estimate normals with a fixed radius
        CGAL::pca_estimate_normals<Concurrency_tag>
            (points,
                0, // when using a neighborhood radius, K=0 means no limit on the number of neighbors returns
                CGAL::parameters::point_map(CGAL::First_of_pair_property_map<PointVectorPair>()).
                normal_map(CGAL::Second_of_pair_property_map<PointVectorPair>()).
                neighbor_radius(2. * spacing)); // use 2*spacing as neighborhood radius
    }
    else // Use a fixed number of neighbors
    {
        CGAL::pca_estimate_normals<Concurrency_tag>
            (points, nb_neighbors,
                CGAL::parameters::point_map(CGAL::First_of_pair_property_map<PointVectorPair>()).
                normal_map(CGAL::Second_of_pair_property_map<PointVectorPair>()));
    }

    // Orients normals.
    // Note: mst_orient_normals() requires a range of points
    // as well as property maps to access each point's position and normal.
    std::list<PointVectorPair>::iterator unoriented_points_begin =
        CGAL::mst_orient_normals(points, nb_neighbors,
            CGAL::parameters::point_map(CGAL::First_of_pair_property_map<PointVectorPair>()).
            normal_map(CGAL::Second_of_pair_property_map<PointVectorPair>()));
    // Optional: delete points with an unoriented normal
    // if you plan to call a reconstruction algorithm that expects oriented normals.
    points.erase(unoriented_points_begin, points.end());

    /// Convert pointvectorpair to pointvector

    
    std::vector<PNI> points2; // store points
    points2 = convert_function(points);
    ///
    /// use points + normals for surface reconstruction
    ///
    
    // Shape detection
    Efficient_ransac ransac;
    ransac.set_input(points2);
    ransac.add_shape_factory<Plane>();

    std::cout << "Extracting planes...";
    t.reset();
    ransac.detect();

    Efficient_ransac::Plane_range planes = ransac.planes();
    std::size_t num_planes = planes.size();

    std::cout << " Done. " << num_planes << " planes extracted. Time: " << t.time() << " sec." << std::endl;

    // Stores the plane index of each point as the third element of the tuple.
    Point_to_shape_index_map shape_index_map(points, planes);
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < points.size(); ++i) {
        // Uses the get function from the property map that accesses the 3rd element of the tuple.
        int plane_index = get(shape_index_map, i);
        points2[i].get<2>() = plane_index;
    }

    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    std::cout << "Generating candidate faces...";
    t.reset();

    Polygonal_surface_reconstruction algo(
        points,
        Point_map(),
        Normal_map(),
        Plane_index_map()
    );

    std::cout << " Done. Time: " << t.time() << " sec." << std::endl;

    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    Surface_mesh model;

    std::cout << "Reconstructing...";
    t.reset();

    if (!algo.reconstruct<MIP_Solver>(model)) {
        std::cerr << " Failed: " << algo.error_message() << std::endl;
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    const std::string& output_file("data/cube_result_47038.off");
    std::ofstream output_stream(output_file.c_str());
    if (output_stream && CGAL::write_off(output_stream, model)) {
        // flush the buffer
        output_stream << std::flush;
        std::cout << " Done. Saved to " << output_file << ". Time: " << t.time() << " sec." << std::endl;
    }
    else {
        std::cerr << " Failed saving file." << std::endl;
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    // Also stores the candidate faces as a surface mesh to a file
    Surface_mesh candidate_faces;
    algo.output_candidate_faces(candidate_faces);
    const std::string& candidate_faces_file("data/cube_candidate_faces_47038.off");
    std::ofstream candidate_stream(candidate_faces_file.c_str());
    if (candidate_stream && CGAL::write_off(candidate_stream, candidate_faces)) {
        // flush the buffer
        output_stream << std::flush;
        std::cout << "Candidate faces saved to " << candidate_faces_file << "." << std::endl;
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}



#else

int main(int, char**)
{
    std::cerr << "This test requires either GLPK or SCIP.\n";
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

#endif  // defined(CGAL_USE_GLPK) || defined(CGAL_USE_SCIP)
```

Thank you,

Barbara

Comment: "syntax is not correct": Can you be more specific?

Comment: yes certainly, the error right now is C2676: "binary '[': 'const std::list<PointVectorPair,std::allocator<PointVectorPair>>' does not define this operator or a conversion to a type acceptable to the predefined operator" . I literally tried everything, changing [] to <>, working with .insert()...  I constantly get similar errors

Comment: Does this error refer to anywhere in particular in the program?

Comment: yes, line 7 in the convert_function: out[i ...

Answer (score 0):

You try to use operator[] on a list:

```
std::vector<PNI> convert_function(const std::list<PointVectorPair>& list)
{
...
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < list.size(); ++i)
    {   
        out[i].get<0>() = list[i].get<0>();
```

You simply cannot do `list[i]` because `std::list` doesn't offer it.

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list

Instead you can use:

```
auto it = list.begin();
```

and

```
it != list.end();
```

and

```
it++;
```

combined with

```
(*it).get<0>();
```

that lets you start at the beginning, detect the end and advance an iterator. Combined with a dereference of the iterator.

You will also need to `resize()` your `out` vector, before trying to write to it.